# SQL - Minimum from a JOIN

Tags: sql, join, teradata

I am joining several tables. From the joined table I need to select a record with the minimum value in one column. The where clause contains some additional conditions.  How can this be achieved without having to  list the whole join twice in the select and in the where clause to identify the minimum?

I mean - from the result of the join, I need to select one record that fullfills some conditions and that also includes a minimum in a specific column. It is in Teradata but I am asking about the general principle.

I have something like this. It works, but is ugly as the join is included twice.

```
SELECT TABLE1.X, TABLE2.Y, TABLE3.Z  
FROM TABLE1  
INNER JOIN TABLE2     
ON TABLE1.A = TABLE2.B  
INNER JOIN TABLE3  
ON TABLE2.C=TABLE3.D  
WHERE TABLE3.M =  
   (SELECT MIN(TABLE3.M)
    FROM TABLE1  
    INNER JOIN TABLE2  
    ON TABLE1.A = TABLE2.B  
    INNER JOIN TABLE3  
    ON TABLE2.C=TABLE3.D
    WHERE TABLE1.K=123 AND TABLE2.L=456
   )
```

Thanks, R.

Comment: "the joined table". There are three joined tables, so your question is not clear.  Also tag with the database you are using.  And what does the filtering in the subquery do?  It is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: I am joining 3 tables. From the final result I need one record that fulfills some conditions (WHERE TABLE1.K=123 AND TABLE2.L=456) and has the minimum in one column (MIN(TABLE3.M). It is Teradata. But I am asking about the principle. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you say you only need one row as your output.

In which case, use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT TABLE1.X, TABLE2.Y, TABLE3.Z  
FROM TABLE1  
INNER JOIN TABLE2     
ON TABLE1.A = TABLE2.B  
INNER JOIN TABLE3  
ON TABLE2.C=TABLE3.D  
WHERE TABLE1.K=123 AND TABLE2.L=456
ORDER BY TABLE3.M
LIMIT 1
```

Edit: (To use `min()` to fulfil unstated requirements...)

```
SELECT
    X, Y, Z
FROM
(
    SELECT
        TABLE1.X,
        TABLE2.Y,
        TABLE3.Z,
        TABLE3.M,
        MIN(TABLE3.M) OVER () AS MIN_M
    FROM
        TABLE1  
    INNER JOIN
        TABLE2     
            ON TABLE1.A = TABLE2.B  
    INNER JOIN
        TABLE3  
            ON TABLE2.C = TABLE3.D  
    WHERE
            TABLE1.K = 123
        AND TABLE2.L = 456
)
    AS FILTERED
WHERE
    MIN_M = M
```

Even if I was going to use window functions for this, I'd use `ROW_NUMBER()` OR `RANK()` rather than using `MIN()`. Without a clear reason WHY you feel this MUST use it, yet still be DRY, efficient and maintainable, this constraint appears not only pointless, but misguided.

Comment: Yes, this works. But I was trying to find a way how to write this using MIN, not ORDER BY.

Comment: Then you really need to either reword your question, to explain What your are Actually trying to achieve or learn, and why, or you need to rethink why you're proscribing the mechanism by which a problem must be solved.  (For what you've described, using MIN() in the way you are, is objectively slower, more complicated, and harder to maintain.)

Comment: Hi, apppologies. I have started learning SQL some 2 months ago, so I am getting familiar with the terminology etc. Point is that I feel like building the same table twice (in From and in Where part). Is there a way how to build it just once and than refer it? When I tried this I kept receiving error like object does not exist - issue with processing order. Thanks for patience...

Comment: You're operating on false assumptions. SQL is a declarative language, not an imperative one. The database takes your query and generates a "plan", which is actually what gets executed. Much like compilers can optimise code, but more so. The question should be be about the most appropriate SQL pattern to solve a functional problem, NOT how to condense a proscribed solution. Learn SQL patterns, then learn why they work, rather than trying to force bad patterns to read more clearly.

Comment: I cannot say I understand you. But you definitelly helped me. The MIN(TABLE3.M) OVER () AS MIN_M solution works. Thank you.

Comment: Please upvote and/or accept answers that have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Use min window function as follows:

```
Select x, y, z from
(SELECT TABLE1.X, TABLE2.Y, TABLE3.Z,
       Min(TABLE3.M) over () as mn,
       TABLE3.M
FROM TABLE1  
INNER JOIN TABLE2     
ON TABLE1.A = TABLE2.B  
INNER JOIN TABLE3  
ON TABLE2.C=TABLE3.D 
Where TABLE1.K=123 AND TABLE2.L=456 ) t
Where m = mn
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am following correctly, you can use `qualify`:

```
SELECT TABLE1.X, TABLE2.Y, TABLE3.Z  
FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN
     TABLE2     
     ON TABLE1.A = TABLE2.B INNER JOIN
     TABLE3  
     ON TABLE2.C = TABLE3.D  
QUALIFY TABLE3.M = MIN(CASE WHEN TABLE1.K = 123 AND TABLE2.L = 456 THEN TABLE3.M END) OVER ();
```